# android:onClick listener for just onTouch in XML

Tags: java, android, onclick, touch-event

I want to use the xml code `android:onClick="OnClickMethod"`.

However, this means that the method will only be called onClick (i.e. in reality the user has to click the editText twice) instead of onTouch.

Is there an equivalent way that I can call the "`OnClickMethod`" on a user touch, instead of user click via XML?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try to use onTouchEvent instead of onClick

This is a good site for performing double click.

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-gesture/

[EDIT 1]

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);     

        editText1.setOnTouchListener(listener);
        editText2.setOnTouchListener(listener); 

    }


OnTouchListener listener = new OnTouchListener() {      
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.editText1:

                break;

             case R.id.editText2:

                break;

            default:
                break;
            }           
            return false;
        }
    };
```

Comment: so android:onTouchEvent="OnClickMethod" in my xml?

Comment: The answer is no. It is not supported in xml.

Comment: The issue is that I want to use a switch statement rather than making a seperate onTouchListener for every single EditText that I have. How else can I call this switch method called "onClickMethod" without making a seperate onTouchListener for every EditText?