# How to Implement OnTouch Listener in XML

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-xml, ontouchlistener

As i know we can define onClick tag in xml after writing in xml we can use in java code easily by name that specify in xml eg

```
<Button android:id="@+id/mybutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="myClick" />

public void myClick(View v) {
    // does something very
}
```

**1) Is any way to define `onTouch` in XML if yes then how to use ???**

**2) Or any other way to implement `onTouch` Listener inside `onClick` listener;**

here my goal is to interact more than 100 buttons without defining Buttons name as mention below: and also have `onTouch` functionality...

```
    Button mbutton;
    mbutton = (Button)findViewbyId(R.id.button);
```

Thanks

Comment: Basically, you can define custom property for that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android:onClick listener for just onTouch in XML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13909217/androidonclick-listener-for-just-ontouch-in-xml)

Comment: @cricket_007 ok but i don't want to use view class as you mention  `EditText editText1;`

Comment: @NigamPatro plz give me an example how to define custom property.??

Comment: Doesn't matter if it is an EditText or a Button. The point is is that it isn't possible with xml.

Comment: @cricket_007 ok is possiable in java ???

Comment: @Attaullah: Simple implement `View.OnTouchListener`  in class in which extending `Button` class add `this.setOnTouchListener(this);` in constructor

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1) Is any way to define onTouch in XML if yes then how to use ???

**No**, there is no default attribute provided by android that lets you define touch event in `xml` file, you have to write the method in .java file.

> 2) Or any other way to implement onTouch Listener inside onClick listener;

**No**, you cannot implement `onTouch()` inside `onClick()` because onClick event gets called when you touch or say click or tap the screen for the first time and performs the event when you release touch. But it is not able to detect the movement of your touch i.e. `ACTION_DOWN`, `ACTION_UP` etc.

So if you want to implement `onTouch()` event, you will have write it on your own.

You can write some mechanism that can let you implement `onTouch()` event easily. But instead of doing that I'd suggest you to use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) library which will let you write `onTouch()` method easily just by defining `annotation`. [Here's the code](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/butterknife-annotations/src/main/java/butterknife/OnTouch.java) how they have binded onTouch() in annotation (in case you want to write your own mechanism).

Comment: acucally i need  ACTION_DOWN and UP in onclick but condition is that not to define View class eg Button mButton direct access method. as mention in my question.

Answer (score 3):

```
Hope this helps some one

You can easily do it using databinding:

step1

public class DataBidingAdapter{

 @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @BindingAdapter("touchme")
    public static void setViewOnTouch(TextView view, View.OnTouchListener listener) {
       view.setOnTouchListener(listener);
    }
}

step 2 in xml

<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>       
        <variable
            name="handlers"
            type="com.user.handlers.Handlers" />

    </data>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">  
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="16dp"
          >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/search"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/search_for_chats_title"
                app:touchme="@{handlers.searchPatient}" />
        </FrameLayout>
</linearLayout>
</layout>
step 3
 public class Handler{
 public boolean searchPatient(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {
          //your code
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: @mochadwi Should it? Maybe this didn't exist in 2015.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, you cant put code directly into XML. Please correct me if I am wrong. You must have code in the Activitys Class.